# try catch in PHP5 PDO

Tags: pdo, try-catch, php-5.5

This is my third day on PHP. I have the following code for selecting data-

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

try
{
   $sql = "SELECT LoginName FROM users WHERE LoginName = :LoginName";
   $statement = $db->prepare($sql); //intentionally used $db here 
   $statement->bindParam(':LoginName', $LoginName, PDO::PARAM_STR, 50);
   $statement->execute();
   $count= $statement->rowCount();
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
   header('Content-Type: application/json');
   echo json_encode(array('result'=>'Error','data'=> $e->getMessage()));    
}
```

I intentionally used `$db` instead of `$conn`. So there supposed to be an exception. But in my ajax call, `$e->getMessage()` has not been sent from `catch` block.

Any help?

Comment: No, it's not an exception. It's a PHP warning for `calling method on null`.Core php does not throw exceptions. PHP supports OOP, but is not natively OOP itself, therefore no PHP language-level error will ever throw an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how it have to be done

First, set this handler ho handle ALL errors that may occur in your script, be it PDO or anything else.

```
set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    error_log("$errstr in $errfile:$errline");
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error', TRUE, 500);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array('result'=>'Error', 'data'=>'Server error'));   
    exit;
}
```

then make your PDO code this way

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = "SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE LoginName = ?";
$statement = $db->prepare($sql); //intentionally used $db here 
$statement->execute([$LoginName]);
$found = $statement->fetchColumn();
```

In essence, you should follow these rules:

- never use try catch operator to report an error
- never reveal a real error to an outsider. Just a generic message

Comment: Anywhere in a configuration file

Comment: configuration file means php.ini?

Comment: No. You cannot write PHP code in php.ini. In your application's configuration file.

Comment: If you don't have one, just write it at the top of your current code.